# How to get the Ubuntu wallpapers on Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-background, gnome-control-center

I am currently running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, and although those who maintain GNOME for Ubuntu claim that they do update the wallpapers every new release, either it's not updating, or it just looks so similar it is almost unnoticeable. So I am wondering if there is any easy way for me to install the current Ubuntu (with Unity) wallpapers on Ubuntu GNOME so that they will also show up in the `Backgrounds` section in the `gnome-control-center` along with the other wallpaper that comes with Ubuntu GNOME? Is there like a package or something that comes with them in it? Or how can I do it without just install the normal Ubuntu and copying them over from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the wallpaper used in Ubuntu (with Unity) run (replacing `<release>` with the appropriate release name, for instance, you could replace it with `wily` or `trusty` to get the wallpaper loaded with 14.04 or 15.10):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers-<release>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think it would be so easy! :)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Nice edit!